# Overflow: hidden not applying to a pseudo element in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, pseudo-element

I'm generating a 'gray theme' - and although there are still some tweaks to be made, I'm fairly happy with it.

- [Gray Theme](http://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/EaQxyW)

But I seem to have stumbled across an issue here in terms of the button in Chrome (other browsers seem ok) where the hover effect seems to give unwanted results.

If I hover the menu, then proceed to hover the 'Test Button', the pseudo element doesn't adhere to the border-radius, giving square corners on `hover`.

[image]

I would be looking for the pseudo element to adhere to the border radius.

My Code for the button is:

```js
+ function() {
  var to;
  $(".wrap").on('mouseenter', function() {
    var circles = $(this).find(".circle");
    var degree = (2 * Math.PI) / circles.length; //calc delta angle
    var transforms = [];

    // Calculate the position for each circle
    circles.each(function(index) {
        var x = 100 * Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI + degree * (-1 * index - 0.5));
        var y = 100 * Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI + degree * (-1 * index - 0.5));

      transforms.push('translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)');
    });

    // Function to moves all the circles
    // We'll pop a circle each time and than call this function recursively
    function moveCircles() {
      var transform = transforms.shift();
      circles.css('transform', transform);

      circles.splice(0, 1);
      if (circles.length) to = setTimeout(moveCircles, 400);
    }

    moveCircles();
  });

  $(".wrap").on('mouseleave', function() {
    var circles = $(this).children().css('transform', '');
    clearTimeout(to);
  });
}();
```

```css
html, body {
    background:darkgray
}

/*****************Radial Menu (plus bit of button)***********************/

.wrap {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition:all 0.8s;
}
.circle {
    transition:all 0.8s;
    position:absolute;
    height:5px;
    width:5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 2px);
    left: calc(50% - 2px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.parent{
     transition:all 0.8s;
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index:8;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px black, inset 0 0 15px black, 0 0 15px black;
}
.parent:before,.parent:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    transition:all 0.8s;
    height:5px;
    width:25px;
    top:22px;
    left:12px;
    background:black; 
    opacity:1;
}
.parent:before{
  top:15px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 0 black;
}
.parent:hover:before,.parent:hover:after{
    transform:translate(0,20px);
    color:gray;
    opacity:0;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 0 none;
}
.wrap:hover .parent,.wrap:hover .parent:before,.wrap:hover .parent:after{
    background:darkgray;
}
.wrap:hover .parent:before{
    box-shadow:none;
}
.wrap:hover .circle {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px black, inset 0 0 15px black, 0 0 15px black;
}
.circle img {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.circle:before {
    border-radius:50%;
    transition:all 0.8s;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}
.circle:after,button:after {
    transition:all 0.8s;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:200%;
    width:200%;
    top:50%;
    left:200%;
    z-index:8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1);
}
.circle:hover:after,button:hover:after {
    left:-200%;
    top:-50%;
}
.circle:hover:before {
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px black, inset 0 0 15px black, 0 0 15px black;
}

/********************Button************************/

button {
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    background:gray;
    outline:0;
    border:0;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px transparent, inset 0 0 15px transparent, 0 0 15px black;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition:all 0.4s;
    overflow:hidden;
}
button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 8px black, inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 18px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr/>
hover near the menu to open
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parent"></div>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/56729.png" />
    </div>
     <div class="circle">
        <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/54976.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="circle">Just Text</div>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/56582.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
then hover button
<button>Test Button</button>
```

Is there a way to stop the button's pseudo from appearing in front of the actual elements border radius (the effect is to generate a 'shine')?

---

**Instructions to reproduce**

- Run snippet in chrome
- Hover radial menu
- Now hover button
- See the 'square corners' of the button's pseudo as the animation finishes.

---

**What I'm getting presently:**

[image]

**What I'm looking to get**

[image]

I am getting this issue (it seems) in the latest version of chrome.

---

**Point to note**

This same effect is being used on the radial menu perfectly, so i'm not sure as to why it's occurring on the button instance?

Is there a way to ensure this doesn't occur in production so that this 'square corner' doesn't appear (issue only in latest chrome it seems)?

---

**Updates**

- Another User has reported that;

> right click on button, left click inspect element and hover just before the dev tools open =>bug (also the "hover out" effect has the bug)

will reproduce this issue.

- And yet another user cannot reproduce this issue at all (on V.24)

Comment: It seems to happen *randomly*.

Comment: @BoltClock: would you be able to suggest a work around for this at all?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I got nothin'.

Comment: @BoltClock: I suppose it's time to talk to chrome devs, then :(. Could I ask how you were able to repro? As I stated, or some other way? Speaking to others in chat suggested they could repro in different ways?

Comment: I tried it with hovering the menu, without, etc, and it all happened at random.

Comment: [issue reported / ticket opened here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=458993&thanks=458993&ts=1424094382)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m by first hovering the radial menu and then hovering the button. If you remove your jQuery code, then you should see the same issue on hover of the radial menu as well.

Comment: I've had a history of issues with Chrome and hover , border radius and shadows on CSS3 with slightly older chrome (don't remember the version but ~5 months ago) giving a very similar look to the issue you're having here. I don't remember finding a solution

Comment: Mac OS X, Chrome 40 - all is fine

Comment: Here is a similar item - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693219/issue-while-using-css-transitions-opacity-change-overflow-hidden/31698580#31698580

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should all read more about css [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) property, you can find one useful article [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/). It is an experimental technology, currently supported by Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

> The will-change CSS property provides a way for authors to hint
>   browsers about the kind of changes to be expected on an element, so
>   that the browser can setup appropriate optimizations ahead of time
>   before the element is actually changed. These kind of optimizations
>   can increase the responsiveness of a page by doing potentially
>   expensive work ahead of time before they are actually required.

It helps your browser to render element transitions using GPU by preparing the layers before the transition occurs. It helps in this case, we just have to be careful with setting this property. We should not set `will-change` to every element on page, but should target specific elements in moment when transition is about to happen. That is why we should use `:hover` state on parent element like this:

```
.will_change:hover *,
.will_change:hover *:before,
.will_change:hover *:after {
    will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

`.will-change` is the class of parent element, you can see details on [updated CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbYBEg).

If we would like to analyze when and why this happens in Chrome, than I can tell you what I noticed:

- It does not happen randomly as [boltclock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) wrote above, but only while browser renders other transition same time. Only after hovering the Menu above (while that animation is still not finished) and we started new one over the button. On your example, if you hover the Button from below or sideways, than you can see no glitches.
- My guess is: using `will-change` forces graphic acceleration and that saves CPU for making mistakes. Similar trick with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px)` helped with text rendering on Chrome.

Comment: This is interesting. It seems to fix the bug but the frame rate is lower than without that property.

Comment: Yes, think it forces graphic acceleration... maybe CSS could be more accurate, but I could not find a better way to implement it.