# Border radius and overflow aren't respected when animation is added on a different element

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I got a weird behavior when working with `transform` in CSS3.

Here is my code:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn_exchange a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #0ea2d3;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 rgba(7, 154, 190, 0.75);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

a.abc {
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear 0s infinite alternate;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}

#box_avatar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 62.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 62.5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 62.5px;
    -o-border-radius: 62.5px;
    border-radius: 62.5px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#img_avatar {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 62.5px;
}

#bg_gray {
    background: #4c4747;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 10px 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#bg_gray img {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_exchange fl bad">
  <a class="button abc" href="#">Button</a>
</div>

<div id="box_avatar">
  <img id="img_avatar" src="http://i.imgur.com/O29DJOZ.jpg" alt="avatar" />
  <div id="bg_gray">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m5qIRID.png" alt="btn_camera" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn_exchange fl good">
  <a class="button abc" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

The problem happens when I use the `.bad` div (remove `.good` div) then the gray background which contains the camera-icon does not lay inside the circle image.

If I remove the animation `transform` in CSS, the button won't pulse anymore but the gray background will be inside circle image.

Anyone know what it is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is quite similar to the one that [I had answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693219/issue-while-using-transitions-opacity-change-overflow-hidden/31698580#31698580). The reason why the gray box with the camera icon is not contained within the circle (not cropped by the circle) is because of how layers are created and accelerated rendering is performed by browsers. You can find more information about it in the answer that I had linked earlier.

**Solution:**

The solution to your problem would be to move the pulsing buttons to a layer higher by setting a higher `z-index` value to it. In the below snippet, I have set it to 1 and you can see that it solves the problem.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn_exchange a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #0ea2d3;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 rgba(7, 154, 190, 0.75);
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
a.abc {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}
#box_avatar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 62.5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#img_avatar {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 62.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bg_gray {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 8px 0 10px 0;
  background: #4c4747;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#bg_gray img {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_exchange fl bad">
  <a class="button abc" href="#">Button</a>
</div>

<div id="box_avatar">
  <img id="img_avatar" src="http://i.imgur.com/O29DJOZ.jpg" alt="avatar" />
  <div id="bg_gray">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m5qIRID.png" alt="btn_camera" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn_exchange fl good">
  <a class="button abc" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

Applying a `z-index` for the `#box_avatar` would also solve the issue.

---

**Reason:**

Rendering and compositing are tricky to explain but the following is what happens when no `z-index` or `z-index: 0` is set to the `a.abc`:

- The `a.abc` gets its own rendering and compositing layer because it has an animated transform and explicit positioning properties.
- The rendering and compositing layer creation process is explained in [this article](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome). The layers can be seen by enabling the "Show Paint Rects" and "Show composited layer borders" in Dev tools.
- The `#box_avatar` and `#bg_gray` also get their own compositing layer. The `#box_avatar` seems to be getting a separate layer because it has a previous sibling with equal or lower `z-index`.
- I am not able to exactly pinpoint why the `#bg_gray` gets a separate layer but it seems to mostly be because of how `z-index: auto` creates a separate stacking context. ([Source - W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html))

When distinct layers are created for `#box_avatar`, `#bg_gray` and they are placed one on top of the other, the `#bg_gray` isn't exactly *inside* the `#box_avatar` and so doesn't respect the `overflow` and `border-radius`. It is kind of like placing two layers of paper one on top of the other.

---

**Detailed Explanation of Solution:**

When `z-index: 1` is assigned on `a.abc` element:

- The `a.abc` gets its own rendering and compositing layer because it has an animated transform.
- The container of `a.abc` also gets its layer because it has a child which has a compositing layer.
- Neither `#box_avatar` nor `#bg_gray` get a separate compositing layer because they don't meet any of the criteria defined to get a compositing layer.

When `z-index: 0` is assigned on `a.abc` and `z-index: 1` is assigned on `#box_avatar`:

- The `a.abc` gets its own rendering and compositing layer because it has an animated transform
- The container of `a.abc` also gets its layer because it has a child which has a compositing layer
- The `#box_avatar` gets its own rendering and compositing layer because it has a sibling (`a.abc` element's container) which has a compositing layer with lower `z-index`.
- The `#bg_gray` becomes a part of the `#box_avatar` element's layer and gets no separate layer.

In both the above cases, because the `#box_avatar` and `#bg_gray` don't get separate layers, they are kind of painted together and so the `#bg_gray` knows where to get cropped.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to place the camera-icon above avatar and set z-index for gray background and avatar. It solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I had a look and can't see why it behaves like that, so would it be okay if to skip the img element and use background image instead?</strike>

If so, here is a sample that does work.

Another option is to combine `background` and `pseudo` instead of `img`. This will give you a cleaner html structure and as well solve your issue.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn_exchange a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #0ea2d3;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 rgba(7, 154, 190, 0.75);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

a.abc {
    z-index: 0;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}

#box_avatar {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 62.5px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/O29DJOZ.jpg);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#bg_gray {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: auto;
}
#bg_gray:before {
    content: "";
    background: #4c4747;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 62.5px;
}
#bg_gray:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/m5qIRID.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_exchange fl bad">
  <a class="button abc" href="#">Button</a>
</div>

<div id="box_avatar">
  <div id="bg_gray"></div>
</div>

<div class="btn_exchange fl good">
  <a class="button abc" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```